# react data grid sticky header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was wondering if anyone has an idea if is it possible to implement a data grid sticky header in react ?

Below I have 3 table pinned into each other since. I've tried different ways to impelement a a sticky header even with the global score but cant seem to figure it out , maybe anyone has an idea would be much appreacited.

Here is my code sandbox. Thanks.

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-frost-13y5td?file=/src/PortfolioPage/PortfolioPage.jsx

#react code

```
export const StyledDataGrid = styled(DataGrid)`
    .MuiDataGrid-row: nth-of-type(odd) {
      background: #E3E0E0
    }
    .MuiDataGrid-cell {
      border-right: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
    }
    .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader  {
      border-right: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
    }
    .MuiDataGrid-columnSeparator--sideRight {
      display: none
    }
    .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitleContainer {
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .MuiDataGrid-iconButtonContainer  {
      visibility: visible;
      width: auto;
    }
`;

const PortfolioPage: FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { isPending, isError, isSuccess, grid, isSaveSuccess } = useAppSelector(
    (state) => state.region
  );
  const [snackbarOpen, setSnackbarOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState<IRegional | null>(null)

  const rows = grid ? grid.items : [];

  console.log('rows' , rows)


  const fetchGridItems = () => {
     const payload: IPageListApiRequestPayload = {
        accountId: 1,
        sortKey: JSON.stringify([]),
        sortOrder: JSON.stringify([]),
        page: 1,
        pageSize: 100,
        searchString: '',
      };
      dispatch(getRegionGrid(payload));
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    // Save success
    if (isSaveSuccess) {
      setSnackbarOpen(true);
      fetchGridItems();
    }
  }, [isSaveSuccess])
  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady) {
      fetchGridItems();
    }
  }, [router.isReady]);

  const renderList = (data: IEmail) => (
    <div style={{display: 'block'}}>
        <div>Full Name: {data.firstName} {data.lastName}</div>
        <div>Email Address: {data.emailAddress}</div>
    </div>
  )

  const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    {
      field: "associateDirectorofConstructionOps",
      headerName: "Associate Director of Construction Ops",
      minWidth: 300,
      flex: 0.16,
      disableColumnMenu: true,
      renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams<string>) => (
        <>
           {
             params.row.associateDirectorofConstructionOps ? params.row.associateDirectorofConstructionOps.map((prop: IEmail) => renderList(prop))
              : null
           }
        </>
      ),
    },
  ];
  const fixedColumnLeft: GridColDef[] = [
    {
      field: "regionName",
      headerName: "Region Division",
      flex: 0.08,
      minWidth: 100,
      disableColumnMenu: true,
    },
    {
      field: "subRegionName",
      headerName: "Sub-Region",
      flex: 0.15,
      minWidth: 50,
      disableColumnMenu: true,
    },
    {
      field: "marketName",
      headerName: "Market",
      flex: 0.08,
      minWidth: 50,
      disableColumnMenu: true,
    },
  ];
  const fixedColumnRight: GridColDef[] = [
    {
      field: "action",
      disableColumnMenu: true,
      sortable: false,
      renderHeader: () => <></>,
      renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams<string>) => (
        <div
          style={{
            color: "rgb(110 110 110)",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
          }}
        >
          <EditIcon onClick={() => handleClickOpen(params)} />
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ];
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const handleClickOpen = (data: any) => {
    setSelectedRow(data.row);
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  return (
    <Box sx={{ height: "100vh", background: "#EEEAEA" }}>
      <Snackbar
        open={snackbarOpen}
        autoHideDuration={3000}
        onClose={() => setSnackbarOpen(false)}>
        <Alert onClose={() => setSnackbarOpen(false)} severity="success" sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
              Successfully saved!
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
      <EditProperties open={open} handleClose={handleClose} selectedRow={selectedRow} />
      <DashboardWrapper seoProps={{
        title: "PIM | Regions",
        }}
        title="Properties"
        mainClass="properties-page">
        {isError ? <div>Error Loading Regions!</div> : ""}
        {isPending ? <>Loading Regions...</> : ""}
        {isSuccess ? (
        <>
            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
                width: "636px",
                height: "56px",
                background: "rgba(37, 36, 41, 0.9)",
                padding: "8px 16px 8px 8px",
                borderBottomRightRadius: "30px",
              }}
            >
              <Input
                size="small"
                style={{
                  width: "461px",
                  height: "40px",
                  background: "#FFFFFF",
                  borderRadius: "4px",
                  outline: "none",
                }}
                placeholder="Search  by typing property name or address"
                startAdornment={
                  <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <SearchIcon />
                  </InputAdornment>
                }
              />
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}
              >
                Search
              </Button>
              <div
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  color: "#FFFFFF",
                  flexDirection: "column",
                  justifyContent: "space-between",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  marginRight: "10px",
                }}
              >
                <TuneIcon style={{ fontSize: "32px" }} />
                <span style={{ fontSize: "10px", marginTop: "-5px" }}>
                  Filters
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <TableContainer component={Paper} style={{ marginTop: "24px" }}>
              <div
                style={{
                  borderBottom: "1px solid #C4C4C4",
                  padding: "16px",
                  display: "flex",
                  justifyContent: "space-between",
                  background: "#FFFFFF",
                  height: "72px",
                }}
              >
                <label
                  style={{
                    fontWeight: "600",
                    fontSize: "24px",
                    color: "#252429",
                    alignSelf: "center",
                  }}
                >
                  {" "}
                  Regions{" "}
                </label>
                <div
                  style={{
                    alignSelf: "center",
                    color: "#C4C4C4",
                    display: "flex",
                    fontSize: "16px",
                  }}
                >
                  <IosShareIcon style={{ marginRight: "14px" }} />
                  Export
                </div>
              </div>
              {/* Table container */}
              <div style={{position: "relative", display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                  {/* Left table */}
                  <Box
                    sx={{ boxShadow: 5 }}
                    style={{
                      width: "20%",
                   
                      zIndex: 99,
                      overflow: "hidden",
                      background: "#FFFFFF",
                    }}
                  >
                    <StyledDataGrid
                      autoHeight 
                      getRowId={(row) => row.accountId}
                      hideFooterPagination={true}
                      components={{
                        ColumnSortedAscendingIcon: UnfoldMoreIcon,
                        ColumnSortedDescendingIcon: UnfoldMoreIcon,
                      }}
                      rows={rows}
                      columns={fixedColumnLeft}
                      disableSelectionOnClick
                      experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
                    />
                  </Box>

                  {/* Center table */}
                <div style={{overflow: 'hidden', width: '70%'}}>
                  <div style={{ width: '2000px', margin: 'auto', overflow: "hidden"}} >
                    <StyledDataGrid
                      autoHeight 
                      getRowId={(row) => row.accountId}
                      components={{
                        ColumnSortedAscendingIcon: UnfoldMoreIcon,
                        ColumnSortedDescendingIcon: UnfoldMoreIcon,
                      }}
                      rows={rows}
                      columns={columns}
                      pageSize={100}
                      rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 20, 50, 100]}
                      disableSelectionOnClick
                      experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>

                  {/* Right table */}
                  <Box
                    sx={{ boxShadow: 5 }}
                    style={{
                      width: "10%",
                      zIndex: 99,
                      overflow: "hidden",
                      background: "#FFFFFF",
                    }}
                  >
                    <StyledDataGrid
                      autoHeight 
                      getRowId={(row) => row.accountId}
                      hideFooterPagination={true}
                      components={{
                        ColumnSortedAscendingIcon: UnfoldMoreIcon,
                        ColumnSortedDescendingIcon: UnfoldMoreIcon,
                      }}
                      rows={rows}
                      columns={fixedColumnRight}
                      disableSelectionOnClick
                      experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
                    />
                  </Box>
              </div>
            </TableContainer>
            {/* <ActionButtonContainer
              btnNameOne="Property"
              btnNameTwo="Properties"
              btnIconOne={<UploadFileIcon />}
              btnIconTwo={<AddIcon />}
            /> */}
          </>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </DashboardWrapper>
    </Box>
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/layout/ AKA, if you set max height I think headers should become sticky on itself.

Comment: No Sir , it does not work apprantely

Comment: my issue is that I have 3 tables being pinned to each other

Answer (score -1):

For FluentUI 9 I used this:

```
.fui-DataGrid{
  position: relative;
}
.fui-DataGridHeader{
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```